# Android Listview Listitem state color

Tags: android, android-listview, drawable, background-color, listitem

I've the following problem: I made a custom state selector for Android Buttons. They work like expected. The problem begins when I want the same states to apply to a ListView item row.

So I set the style in the Adapter and now I discover that the same state looks different on the listbox view item. It is more of a blend between the default style and the color I want to set. When I long press the item or release the item, I notice that it fades away first into the default color (blue) and then transparent.

I guess I do miss some state/state combination, but I can't figure out which. I tried a lot, also examples from StackOverflow, but nothing works. Hopefully someone here had the same challenge and has a correct override. Below is my drawable selector.

Thanks in advance!

**XML:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
> 

    <item   android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<item   android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<item   android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<item   android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

<item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

<item   android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

In touch mode there is no such thing as selected or focused when you are not pressing on an item.

But you can work around it.  You need to set choice mode for the list (single or multiple, the default is.none) and then use `state_activated` in your selector.